# Intent is not giving back the result

Tags: android

I create an application in which I am retrieving the contacts from MainActivity to SmsSend. On activity result method,but it is not giving back the result in it.So that on that contacts user can send the messages.

SmsSend.java

```
    package com.example.smscampaign;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;





    public class SmsSend extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        BroadcastReceiver smsSentReciver, smsSentDelivery;
        static EditText edName, edMessage;
        static int ResultCode = 12;
        static ArrayList<String> sendlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        Button btnSaveForLater, btnStart, btnExternal, btnSelect;
        static TextView txt;
        static StringBuilder conct = new StringBuilder();
        static String contacts = "";
        String delim = ";";
        public static String Name;

        int i = 0;

        String Name1, msg, msg1;
        String[] cellArray;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.create_camp);


            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



            edName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    edName.setError(null);
                }
            });
            edMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    edMessage.setError(null);
                }
            });
            txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    txt.setError(null);
                }
            });
            // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), contacts.toString(),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Name1 = edName.getText().toString();

            msg1 = edMessage.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
            edName.setText(null);
            edMessage.setText(null);
            conct.delete(0, conct.length());
            contacts = null;
            txt.setText("0");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            unregisterReceiver(smsSentReciver);
            unregisterReceiver(smsSentDelivery);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();

            smsSentReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sms has been sent",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Fail",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                    }
                }

            };
            smsSentDelivery = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms Delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms not Delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            };
            registerReceiver(smsSentReciver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
            registerReceiver(smsSentDelivery, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatabaseHelp entry = new DatabaseHelp(SmsSend.this);
            entry.open();
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnSelect:

                Intent a = new Intent(SmsSend.this, MainActivity.class);

                a.putExtra("rowid", rowid);
                startActivity(a);
                break;
            case R.id.btnExternal:
                Intent file = new Intent(SmsSend.this, File_Selecter.class);
                startActivity(file);
                break;



        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == ResultCode) {

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        sendlist = data.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
                    if (sendlist != null) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < sendlist.size(); i++) {
                            conct.append(sendlist.get(i).toString());
                            conct.append(delim);
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), conct.toString(),
                                //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }

                }

                i = sendlist.size();
                txt.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                }

            }
        }


    }


MainaActivity.java



package com.example.smscampaign;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;




import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma;
    Button send;
    String[] cellArray = null;
    int[] str;
    int v = 0;
    String contacts;
    static int check1;
    ListView lv;
    int index;
    int top;
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // b = SmsSend.contacts;

        contacts = SmsSend.contacts;
        //if (SmsSend.contacts != null) {
            cellArray = contacts.split(";");
            // Toast.makeText(getApplication(),contacts.toString(),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (int i = 0; i < cellArray.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < phno1.size(); j++) {

                    if (cellArray[i].equals(phno1.get(j))) {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplication(),cellArray[i].toString(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ma.setChecked(j, true);

                    }
                }

            }
        }

    //}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_main, menu);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addPage:

            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println(".............." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

        {
            if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString());
                checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                checkedcontacts.append("\n");

            } else {
                System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                        + name1.get(i).toString());
            }

        }
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, checkedcontacts, 1000).show();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();

    }



}
```

Comment: Where is `startActivityForResult()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ref Below link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
-----------------------------------------------------------

startService(i1);//Start Service.
Use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() bcoz in service we use startActivityResult()
method bcoz broadcast receiver will give the response of onresultActivity.. so you could use this line

Use startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode) instead of startActivity().
thank you..
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an example function of intent .. modify it a bit

```
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                      String strEmployeeID="";
                      if (extras != null)
                      {

                          String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
//                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          strEmployeeID = value;
                      }


                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yourdesiredclass.class);
                    i.putExtra("new_variable_name",strEmployeeID);
                    startActivity(i); 


            }
```

Comment: This is for getting the value and sending it too.
The first part gets the value from prev page and 2nd part sends it to next page . use it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity()

Answer (score 1):

you should start activity using startActivityForResult(); and also add `@Override` annotation to onActivityResult

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```